How do I fill in missing data when importing json data from Python to MySQL
I am rather new to all of this but I am trying use python to grab API data from a url and push it into a MySQL database. The problem I am running into is that some data is missing from the Json file and that is causing the import to stop and fail with a 'Key Error:'. Is there a way to fill in the blanks with null or is it just bad data? Below is my code.
### Import needed Modules
import requests
import json
import mysql.connector
#from mysql.connector import errorcode


### Create a variable that has the API URL in it

api_url = 'https://prices.runescape.wiki/api/v1/osrs/mapping'

### Create a header variable for the Wiki Admins to see who is requesting the data

headers = {'user-agent': 'volume_tracker -@Discordname'}

### Do a GET request with the API URL variable and header and put answer into a variable

response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)

### An IF statement that checks to make sure the response code is successful
### Puts the data into a variable in json format if successful
### And prints out a confirmation of it working

if response.status_code == 200:
    data = response.json()
    print("Worked!")


#### This section is used to connect to the Mysql Database

### Creates a variable containing connection information

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user = "root",
    password = "password",
    database = "osrsprice")

### Puts the connection into a variable to use with a mysql cursor
    
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

### SQL code used to insert data into testPrices database

sqlcode = """INSERT INTO osrsprice.testPrices
            (
                examine,
                id,
                members,
                lowalch,
                value,
                highalch,
                icon,
                name
            )
            VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""


### This FOR statement takes the data variable and goes through it line-by-line
### Each line is put into the variable 'value', and used in the execute command
### After each instance of i it will commit the data to the database

#The current issue with the below line of code is that not all parts of the json file contain lowalch/highalch
#This causes the command to fail as soon as it hits one that lacks the called for information

for i in data:
    value = i   
    mycursor.execute(sqlcode, (value['examine'],value['id'],value['members'],value['lowalch'],value['value'],value['highalch'],value['icon'],value['name']))
    mydb.commit()

Here is a normal dataset:
{
    "examine": "Fabulously ancient mage protection enchanted in the 3rd Age.",
    "id": 10344,
    "members": true,
    "lowalch": 20200,
    "limit": 8,
    "value": 50500,
    "highalch": 30300,
    "icon": "3rd age amulet.png",
    "name": "3rd age amulet"
  }

Here is where the data fails on imports:
{
    "members": true,
    "name": "Calcified moth",
    "examine": "A fossilised moth infused with dwarven magic.",
    "id": 29090,
    "value": 10000,
    "icon": "Calcified moth 5.png",
    "limit": 100
  }

When I remove the problem fields from the import, everything works and all 4166 rows are entered without the removed data.

don't commit every row run it only once at the end

Thanks for this info. I thought I had to commit each line during the loop but I was able to do that after.

I believe your error is on this line:
mycursor.execute(sqlcode, (value['examine'],value['id'],value['members'],value['lowalch'],value['value'],value['highalch'],value['icon'],value['name']))

Because your value variable is a dict with missing keys, hence your KeyError exception.
What you could do, is simply using the get() method from dict. This will tell Python to use a default value if the key does not exist.
Example:
# Key 'lowalch' is missing
data = {
    "examine": "Fabulously ancient mage protection enchanted in the 3rd Age.",
    "id": 10344,
    "members": true
}

# This will raise a KeyError exception
print(data["lowalch"])

# This will print "unknown"
print(data.get("lowalch", "unknown"))

So in your case, you can do:
mycursor.execute(sqlcode, (value.get('examine', 'unknown'),value.get('id', 'unknown'),value.get('members', 'unknown'),value.get('lowalch', 'unknown'),value.get('value', 'unknown'),value.get('highalch', 'unknown'),value.get('icon', 'unknown'),value.get('name', 'unknown')))


Awesome! This worked for me. I had to adjust the values of lowalch and highalch to be integers instead of string but it worked once I did that. Thanks for the help!

use value.get(‘field_name’, default_value) instead of value[‘field_name’].

Using .get was the solution. Thanks for the help!

NP.. I never use keyed access to dictionaries… I like to control the flow of code and not depend on exceptions if a key isn’t set.
